# How to solve this iGoogle-gadget issue?

Tags: javascript, html, frames, igoogle

I want make an 'iGoogle gadgets' that changes the search box on the igoogle page.
Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function bing(){
  document.getElementById('sfrm').action="http://www.bing.com/search";
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="bing()" value="Search"><br>with Bing.
```

I have tested it briefly with the pages search box code on a separate page, and it worked.
Does it not work because it is in a frame; if so is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that Google probably designed iGoogle to prevent modifying that stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I remember that they had different kind of gadget modes. The one allowing more access on the page had a mode like "inline". I'm not sure however. I just did a quick search on the web with no result however. Maybe they have dropped that, you'd have to search for it.

**//Edit**
Try with

```
<Content type="html-inline">
```

I'm not sure whether it will work, didn't try it out.